# Fixing Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided. In R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would create graph like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jz99.png)

but I encountered problem : Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided

Here is my code

```
Library(ggplot2)

Library(read_xl)

df2 <- read_excel("Data122.xlsx", sheet = "sheet4")

ggplot(Data=df2) + 
  geom_line(aes(col="COP", 
                x =df2$`Ground Temp T1 Tg`, 
                y=df2$`Daily COP`), size= 2) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "Entering source temperature EST", y = "COP") + 
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "top") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF3333")) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "COP", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . *1, 
                                         name = "Produced and Consumed power MWh")) + 
  geom_line(aes(col = "Consumed Power", 
                x = df2$`Ground Temp T1 Tg`, 
                y = df2$`Electricity MWh day`), size= 2)
**Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided**
```

Comment: Well, you need to supply a second color in `scale_color_manual`. Also, remove `df2$` from inside `aes`. It's not needed and can lead to surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

I would need as sample of your data to be sure, but your issues is in `scale_color_manual()`. You supplied a single color value to map to the data, but there must be two values in the data to map. If you want everything to be that color, don't map color as an aesthetic, just provide it as a parameter:

```
 geom_line(aes(x =df2$`Ground Temp T1 Tg`, 
               y=df2$`Daily COP`), size = 2, color = "#FF3333")
```

Here are some other pointers about your code. In your `aes()` mappings, you have `df2$`. You don't need that. The whole reason of providing `data =`  in the original `ggplot()` call is to avoid this.

```
 geom_line(aes(x = `Ground Temp T1 Tg`, 
               y = `Daily COP`), size = 2, color = "#FF3333")
```

Your `geom_point()` layer has no aesthetics mapped, nor are there any defined in the `ggplot()` call. Layers do not inherit aesthetics from other layers. Your plot will not have any points on it.